# There is an error in installing alias mongo in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, web, mongodb-query

I have installed mongoDB successfully and now I am trying to setup it so that I can use it through hyper. Using hyper terminal in my home directory I have created a file .bash_profile And by using vim editor I edited it as,

```
alias mongod = "/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe"     
alias mongo = "/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe"
```

and saved it using the cammand :wq! enter. Now the terminal is showing,

```
bash: alias: mongod: not found bash: alias: =: not found bash: alias: /C/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe: not found
bash: alias: mongo: not found bash: alias: =: not found bash: alias: /C/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongo.exe: not found
```

How can I fix it?

The result had to be:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.1",
    "gitVersion": "ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to add `c:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin` to your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Is there a reason to use hyper terminal?